# Return value of filled JComboBox and using the values to fill JTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, jcombobox

I'm coding a JFrame which opens a JOptionPane through JMenubar. The JOptionPane does have a combobox with a lot of different string values. After the JComboBox there is a JTextfield.

I want the text I select in the JComboBox to be inserted into the next JTextField and to be updated everytime I select a new string value in the JComboBox.

Please help!

```
class DateiAdapter implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    JMenuItem change = (JMenuItem) event.getSource();

    JComboBox alleQuest = new JComboBox(ah.getLine(1)); //this ComboBox gets a lot of different values from a different class

    // Actionlistener
    ActionListener cbActionListener = new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String s = (String) allQuest.getSelectedItem(); //gets the selected string of the JComboBox
            System.out.println("\n" + s); // I want to use String s outside of here, too
            }
        };

        allQuest.addActionListener(cbActionListener);

        JTextField questions = new JTextField(); //THIS is the TextField I want to insert the different values of the ComboBox above
        JTextField a2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField b2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField c2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answ2 = new JTextField();

        if (change == itemChange) {

            final JComponent[] input = new JComponent[] {
                    new JLabel("You change your question here:"),
                    allQuest,
                    quest2,
                    a2,
                    b2,
                    c2,
                    answ2,  };

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input, "Change Question", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
questions.setText(alleQuest.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

inside the ActionListener.
But questions textfileld should be defined above the actionPerformed method

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Heshan!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options regarding

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String s = (String) allQuest.getSelectedItem(); //gets the selected string of the JComboBox
    System.out.println("\n" + s); // I want to use String s outside of here, too
    }
};
```

1. Either store `s` as a field of enclosing class (DateiAdapter class in your case)
2. Update every GUI component you want with given `s` value from the `actionPerformed` method. To be honest this is the exact place to do this as `actionPerformed` is invoked by the EDT, where all GUI changes should happen.
3. In case you want `s` to use outside `DateiAdapter` class, follow point 1, then optionally 2, and add public getter for that field.

In your case putting 
`questions.setText(alleQuest.getSelectedItem().toString());` in the `actionPerformed` would be the most straightforward choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So, this basically, seems to, come down a question of context, the `questions` field needs to be defined in a context in which the `cbActionListener` can reference it.

One of the simplest was would be to make `questions` an instance field of the class, for example...

```
class DateiAdapter implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField questions = new JTextField(); //THIS is the TextField I want to insert the different values of the ComboBox above

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        JMenuItem change = (JMenuItem) event.getSource();

        JComboBox alleQuest = new JComboBox(ah.getLine(1)); //this ComboBox gets a lot of different values from a different class

        // Actionlistener
        ActionListener cbActionListener = new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String s = (String) allQuest.getSelectedItem(); //gets the selected string of the JComboBox
                questions.setText(s);
            }
        };

        allQuest.addActionListener(cbActionListener);

        JTextField a2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField b2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField c2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField answ2 = new JTextField();

        if (change == itemChange) {

            final JComponent[] input = new JComponent[]{
                new JLabel("You change your question here:"),
                allQuest,
                quest2,
                a2,
                b2,
                c2,
                answ2,};

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input, "Change Question", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MadProgrammer, is there a way we could talk for a couple of minutes some day? I'd like to ask you some questions related to programming, I really learn a lot from you and many others here, I'd love to discuss some things with you. If it's possible, just reply and let's exchange our e-mail or something. I promise I won't be annoying :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've been a bit busy, so maybe this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100821/swing-questions) will take me some time to reply, but I'm interested in chatting with you, so, catch you there :)